# Images not loading properly after Next.js building and yarn start

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, image-loading

I'm using amazon s3 as CDN, everything is working fine when I run the application using 'yarn dev'(domain added to next config). If I check inspect I can see the following value in the src attribute of the img element:
src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcf-simple-s3-origin-gallery-hior-021672050205.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com%2FslidesImages%2Flogo.png&w=640&q=75"

When I'm running 'yarn build & yarn start' the src attribute set as the following:
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"

which causing the issue loading the images, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the root cause for that issue(also reproduced with static images).
I added an unnecessary config variable inside the component which disabled the React client-side and causing the loading issue.
*export const config = {
unstable_runtimeJS: false,
};*

Answer (score 0):

though this is probably not the issue, I had a similar problem, just make sure that if you are using ReactJS to have `className` instead of `class`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but I do use className, here is the code:
<Image
            className="animate-fade-in aspect-auto w-72 h-48"
            width="288"
            height="193"
            src="https://cf-simple-s3-origin-gallery-hior-021672050205.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/slidesImages/logo.png"
            alt="logo"
          />